# Ecuación de primer grado java script

Tags: javascript

El ejercicio trata sobre crear un programa que te resuelva una ecuación de primer grado. Creo que fallo en la función, pero lo cambio y cuando quiero ver el resultado en el navegador no me sale nada. Gracias y un Saludo .

```
<html>
    <head>  
        <title>"Ecuación primer grau"</title>   
        <script  type="text/javascript"

            var m, a, b;    
            var a= prompt ("Ingresa el valor de a: ")); 
            var b= prompt ("Ingresa el valor de b: ")); 


            function x1 (a,b){
                if(a !=0) {
                    m = ((-1) * b ) / a;
                    alert ("Resultado de la ecuación: ", m); 

                }else if( b != 0 )
                    alert ("Solución imposible: "); 
                else
                    alert ("Indeterminada Solución: "); 

            </script>
        </head>
    <body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existen varios problemas con tú código.

1. Defines dos veces las variables a y b:
2. Los paréntesis en el prompt, ya un ")" de más:
3. Además en ningún momento invocas la función x1.

Te propongo que coloques un botón y cuando le des click invoque a la función x1.

```
    <button id="btnCalculo">Calcular</button>
    <script>

       const btnCalculo = document.getElementById("btnCalculo");

                function x1 (){
                 var m;    
//parseFloat para convertir string en número flotante
                var a= parseFloat(prompt ("Ingresa el valor de a: ")); 
                var b= parseFloat(prompt ("Ingresa el valor de b: ")); 
                    if(a !=0) {
                        m = ((-1) * b ) / a;
                        alert ("Resultado de la ecuación: "+ m); 

                    }else if( b != 0 ){
                        alert ("Solución imposible: "); 
                    }
                    else{
                        alert ("Indeterminada Solución: "); 
                    }
                 }

             //Creo el evento click 
             btnCalculo.addEventListener("click",x1);
    </script>﻿
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: Gracias por ayudar .